# Switch condition evaluates incorrectly on zero

Tags: php, switch-statement

I was trying a piece of code like this:

```
$event = 0;

switch ($event) {
    case 'content':
        echo "/content";
        break;
    case 'start':
        echo "/start";
        break;
    default :
        echo "not available";
        break;
}
```

This code prints `/content` when is executed, so... 0 (zero, integer, assigned to $event variable) is being evaluated as 'content'. **Why?**

Comment: integer `content  == 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what is actually happening

```
0 == 'content'
```

Php tries to cast the string `content` to an integer. Since `content` doesnt equal an int, it just defaults to 0.

Resulting in:

```
0 == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

An implicit conversion from one type to another takes place.

The intval('content') is 0.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the way operators are defined in php when mixing numeric and string  variables: When the string has no valid number, it is handled as 0

```
So:
1+"xxx" => 1+0=1
0=="xxxx =>  0==0=>true
etc..
```

It's just the way php designed. I don't like it btw